# Changing the PDO bindColumn data type for date fields

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

When I use PDO to bind a columns as:

```
$employeeRecSet->bindColumn ('hireddate', $this->HiredDate);
```

is of type string, even if my field is defined as Date in my postgresql DB. Is there a way to have $this->HiredDate be of type date?

The third parameter in ->bindColum () seems to be for data type, but I couldn't find any date type.

Hopefully this question will score higher than my previous question, -2.

Comment: `$this->HiredDate` must be a string representing a date. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There is no date type in PHP. Thus, from bindColumn you can get nothing but string.

Comment: By the way, I see no point in using bindColumn at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you still can use a `\DateTime` instance.

Comment: PDO does output strings and strings only, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643297/pg-query-result-contains-strings-instead-of-integer-numeric