# How to use PHP array in Postgres select

Tags: php, postgresql

I try to use a php array in a postgres select statement.

I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE string_field IN ($1) AND other_field = $2;";

$result = pg_query_params($conn, $sql, array(implode(',', $my_arr), $other_field));
```

But when i run it nothing returns. (when I hardtype everything in postgres, something will be returned)

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? What is the specific error you receive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22663617/870729

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643297/pg-query-result-contains-strings-instead-of-integer-numeric#31740990 for an example with proper array content escaping and PHP conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings needs single quotes as I know. Concat the elements of array like this:

```
$data = ['a','b','c','d'];
$x = "'" . implode("','", $data) . "'";
var_dump($x);
```

Result:

```
'a','b','c','d'
```

Comment: anyway, first let's check, are there values in your array!

Comment: Until there is a quote in your array value strings…

Comment: OP should handle this in `$my_arr` with an `array_map` for escape. I just told him how to join the pieces for strings.