# PostgreSQL integer field is returned as string in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, lumen, postgresql-9.5

I'm using `PHP 7.2.12` and PostgreSQL 9.5.5 and Lumen 7 when i execute a query with query builder, Lumen give me numeric column as string.

```
Table: 
 id: bigint 


{
  id: "1"
}
```

i have searched for and there is answer for [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php) but that does not work for PostgreSQL.

my co-worker does not have this problem in Linux. but i use windows 10 and i don't know what configuration have to set to fix this issue.

Comment: I have check and i see this problem is for only columns with bigint type.

Comment: It is very likely the underlying driver returns the data as text, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643297/pg-query-result-contains-strings-instead-of-integer-numeric/31740990#31740990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot i found this problem is because of [php does not support bigint in 32bit machine](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/bigint) if your machine is x64 so you should check is your php x64 too or not:
you can check it by following script:

```
echo (PHP_INT_SIZE === 8) ? "64 bit " : "32 bit ";
```

this problem is not PDO issue and you cann't solve it with changing PDO options it's because of pgsql driver. [pgsql return bigint as string if the used language doesn't have any type for bigint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168501/pg-promise-returns-integers-as-strings)

Comment: My machine is x64, my PHP is x64, my PostgreSQL is x64, it still return BIGINT but also INT and SMALLINT as string... :/

Comment: @Some_user if you have all int as string i think you should set PDO options to change number to integers